# How do i make the border of android.text.DynamicLayout dynamic change?

Tags: android, text, limit

I has a Android Project Requirements like that:

1. Here is a string of characters to show in override View method    onDraw(Canvas).
2. This string of characters are limited to a fixed rectangle.I know that use android.text.Dynamic-Layout can solved this problem.

But now: I has a another question:

1. User can change the fixed rectangle size real time by drag.
2. User can reset the String to show.

need I to go to the New Dynamic-Layout Object again real time?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Can you change the text: " ... But now: I has a another question:  ..." where is the first question in the first place?

Comment: tried `increaseWidthTo` ? if it doesnt work then yes, you have to create a new `DynamicLayout`

Comment: I feel sorry for my poor English, I tried increaseWidthTo, the implement of this method is                                                                                                              public final void increaseWidthTo(int wid) {
        if (wid < mWidth) {
            throw new RuntimeException("attempted to reduce Layout width");
        }

        mWidth = wid;
    }, It can only increase, not reduce.